# error to segue from ZBar to another view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, zbar-sdk

will like to know how to fix this error.

i will

```
  QRReader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
  [self presentViewController:QRReader animated:YES completion:nil];
```

in customoverlay i have a button that will call

```
 [helpButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToTips) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)goToTips
{
    [QRReader performSegueWithIdentifier:@"scannerToTips" sender:self];
}
```

but when i pressed the button i will get this error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<ZBarReaderViewController: 0x3c5350>) has no segue with identifier 'scannerToTips''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok there are some issues with the code...

1. Seques is a feature that must be used in iOS5 (and later) and only if you choose storyboards instead of xibs
2. If you indeed use a seque, you must define an identifier in Interface Builder by clicking on your seque and typing an identifier name in the inspector
3. **A seque is automatically instantiating your destination controller**, so you do not have to do so manually

So a proper call to seque would be:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    ZBarReaderViewController *QRReader = [segue destinationViewController];
    // So to hold a reference and pass any data
}
```

But in your case I'm guessing that you are not using a segue...
So a code like this would be fine:

```
[helpButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToTips) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)goToTips
{
  QRReader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
  [self presentViewController:QRReader animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I hope that this helped...